# MySql UPDATE Multiple Values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to update the sort_id for all my users. For example, since there are 10 users, I want to specify sort_id from 0-9 respectively. I can do it using foreach in PHP, but it causes a lot of performance and time problems. Is there a method to do it without running each update query again?

```
UPDATE users SET sort_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(sort_id)+1 WHERE id IN(100,101,102,103,104)
```

what I really want to do
users

```
#id - #sort_id
100, 0
101, 1
102, 2
103, 3
104, 4
```

Comment: `SET @cnt = -1; UPDATE users AS w SET w.sort_id = @cnt := @cnt + 1 WHERE w.id IN(1,3,5) ORDER BY FIELD(w.id, 1,3,5);` I solved the problem with this method.

Comment: Do you really need the "0-9", or would it suffice to list the rows in some computed order simply?  That would only take a `ORDER BY expression`.

Comment: What version do of MariaDB?  10.2 is required for `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()`.  (In MySQL, 8.0 is required.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to store redundant data which can be calculated by the value of another column from the same table. Data redundancy leads to data anomalies and corruption and should be always avoided in relational database systems.

If you need sort_id only on client side, just use a simple select.

```
SELECT id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 as sort_id
FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 100 and 104
```

If you really want to store the sort_id, then use UPDATE with a subquery:

```
UPDATE users AS u JOIN 
 (SELECT id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1 AS sort_id
  FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 104) as s
ON u.id=s.id SET u.sort_id=s.sort_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number()` function:

```
UPDATE users u
SET sort_id = t.rn
FROM (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM users
) t
WHERE t.id = u.id
```

The subquery assigns a sequential number to the rows, which is then used to update the `sort_id` column.

Comment: RANK, DENSE:RANK,  ROW_NUMBER are doing the same, assuming id is unique (see previous answer)

Comment: @hobby_programmer The main difference between ROW_NUMBER() and RANK() is that ROW_NUMBER() assigns a unique number to each row, whereas RANK() assigns a rank to a group of rows with the same value.

Comment: Since he uses last_insert_id, id is  an auto_increment column.  So  rank(),, dense_rank() and row_number() will all return the same result.

Comment: @hobby_programmerThe same outcome but different function could be used for a variety of tasks.